# Can't add file to TFS because "cannot lock item" of parent folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to add a file to TFS. When I right click on the file and choose "TFS > Add", I receive this message (which has my name in it):

> TF10151: Cannot lock item $/Blah/API Code/packages/folder/file.dll for check-out. The item $/Blah/API Code/packages is checked out by Hoppe, Joseph in Workspace XYZ.

If I look in Source Control Explorer, it reports that the packages folder has a pending change of add, although there are other files checked in underneath of it.

If I right click and do TFS undo, it reports "There are no changes to undo in the selection or any children of the selection".

If I try TF undo, I get the following error:

```
tf undo /workspace:XYZ;Domain\MyDomainAccount $/Blah/API Code/packages/folder/file.dll /server:http://domain:8080/tfs
No pending changes to undo.
```

If I try tf undo * /recursive, I also receive the same message.

I deleted the folder. I then re-got it from TFS. Same issue.

How can I add these files to TFS?  I looked in Source Control Explorer in VS2013 and VS2015.

Can these be locked from before my computer was formatted? If so, how do I unlock it?

Comment: You should not be putting the contents of `packages` in source control. The packages can be restored by NuGet at the time of build.

Comment: I have some dependencies that are not available as packages, so I am storing them in a subfolder of the packages folder